# Value * is not a member of AnyVal

Tags: scala, scala-collections

This is a fold that I wrote and I get this error:

```
Error:(26, 42) value * is not a member of AnyVal
        (candE.intersect(candR), massE * massR)

                           ^
```

`allAssignmentsTable` is a `List[Map[Set[Candidate[A]],Double]]`

```
val allAssignmentsTable = hypothesis.map(h => {
    allAssignments.map(copySet => {
      if(h.getAssignment.keySet.contains(copySet))
        (copySet -> h.getAssignment(copySet))
      else
        (copySet -> 0.0)
    }).toMap
  })

val aggregated  = allAssignmentsTable.foldLeft(initialFold) { (res,element) => 
  val allIntersects = element.map { 
    case (candE, massE) => 
      res.map { 
        case (candR, massR) => candE.intersect(candR), massE * massR
      }.toList
  }.toList.flatten

  val normalizer = allIntersects.groupBy(_._1).filter(_._1.size == 0).map { 
    case(key, value) => value.foldLeft(0.0)((e,i) => i._2 + e)
  }.head

  allIntersects.groupBy(_._1).map { 
    case(key, value) => key -> value.foldLeft(0.0)((e,i) => i._2 + e)
  }
}
```

if I do this: `case(candE, massE:Double)` then I won't get an error but I will get exception in match.

Comment: your code is missing 2 `}` you have 6 `{` but only 4 `}`, without those last two it's hard to determine where exactly your blocks end

Comment: what's the type of `element`?

Comment: element is Map[Set[Candidate[A]],Double]

Comment: add some code that describes how this collection is created.

Comment: If it cannot match this case, then apparently whatever gets into the match, is not (Candidate[A],Double) tuple. Add a catch-all case x:_ => print(x)  (or logger.debug(x) if you use logger) to see what you are getting.

Comment: @Ashalynd It needs a big background of my code to show that ... but I am using IDE and it tells me that the what types are.

Comment: By the way, in tuple (26, 42) the second element doesn't look like Double.

Comment: That's why I am convinced that beginners should not use anything more complex than Sublime, but that's my personal opinion :)

Comment: @Ashalynd Being a beginner in StackOverFlow doesn't entail "being beginner in programming"
I am beginner in Scala anyways ;)

Comment: That's exactly what I meant :) IDE's can be deceiving. From your error it looks like the element in the matching has the wrong type, that much is clear. Do catch-all and see what you get.

Comment: @Ashalynd I added some additional code

Comment: Do a little experiment: specify the type of allAssignmentsTable explicitly: `val allAssignmentsTable:Map[Set[Candidate[A]],Double] =...` - does the compiler eat that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you get here:

```
val aggregated  = allAssignmentsTable.foldLeft(initialFold) { (res,element) => 
  val allIntersects = element.map { 
    case (candE, massE) => 
      res.map { 
        case (candR, massR) => candE.intersect(candR), massE * massR
      }.toList
  }.toList.flatten
```

is most probably arising from the previous code block:

```
val allAssignmentsTable = hypothesis.map(h => {
    allAssignments.map(copySet => {
      if(h.getAssignment.keySet.contains(copySet))
        (copySet -> h.getAssignment(copySet))
      else
        (copySet -> 0.0)
    }).toMap
  })
```

My hypothesis is that h.getAssignment(copySet) returns something else instead of Double (which seems to be confirmed by the error message quoted in the OP - `(26, 42)`etc, neither of these two values look like it is a Double. Therefore, allAssignmentsTable undercover is probably not `List[Map[Set[Candidate[A]],Double]]` but something else e.g. it has Any instead of Double, therefore operator `*` cannot be applied.

Comment: Thanks, I found it! Somewhere I had a Int output 0 instead of 0.0, It is crazy that IntelliJ infer the types in other way that compiler does!

Comment: Good that you've found it, have fun with Scala :)